# Octomap volume estimation

Tags: octomap, octomap-server, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,
I am trying to calculate the volume of octomap generated in octomap_server. Also I only want to calculate the volume containing occupied voxels(not the empty ones). Also some voxels overlap each other. So any  thoughts on calculate the the volume?. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149126/octomap-volume-estimation/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2014-04-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-04-07**:
Don't change your question and replace it with a completely different one! Leave your questions for future reference and post a new one if it's not an addition or clarification on your original question.

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2014-04-08**:
Sorry about that. I have re-posted the new question, here http://answers.ros.org/question/150731/iterating-through-leaves-in-an-octomap/.
Please share your thoughts on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's quite easy if I understand it correctly and you want to compute the volume occupied by all occupied voxels. Just use a [leaf_iterator](http://octomap.github.io/octomap/doc/classleaf__iterator.html) in OctoMap to iterate over all leaf nodes. Then check whether the node is occupied (`tree.isNodeOccupied(*it)`), get the side length of the current voxel (`it.getSize()`) and compute the volume from it.

I'm not sure what you mean with "some voxels overlap". Leaf nodes in the octree cannot overlap.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2014-04-07**:
Hello,
Octomap_server already publishes occupied voxels as a marker topic. Subscribing to those and reading the scale of each voxel will help calculate the volume?. Please let me know. Thank you.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-04-07**:
That should also work, although working on the octomap directly will be more efficient.

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2014-04-07**:
I agree, I want to work on the octomap directly too. Is there a way to subscribe to the topic "occupied_cells_vis_array" given by octomap_server. Then convert it to tree to iterate through the leaves.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-04-07**:
Don't use the topic "occupied_cells_vis_array" unless you need a basic visualization, it's inefficient. Check the documentation of octomap_server, it is publishing the map as octomap_msgs::Octomap. You can deserialize the message with the conversion header in the octomap_msgs package.